# How do I combine the values of a Pandas column from multiple dataframes into one column in one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, series

The dataframes can be created using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.DataFrame({'item':['apple','apple','apple']}, 
                  index=['1/2/2024','1/5/2024','1/6/2024'])
s2 = pd.DataFrame({'item':['orange','orange','orange']}, 
                  index=['1/3/2024','1/5/2024','1/7/2024'])
s3 = pd.DataFrame({'item':['banana','banana','banana','banana']}, 
                  index=['1/4/2024','1/5/2024','1/6/2024','1/7/2024'])
print(s1)
print(s2)
print(s3)
```

The print output looks like this:

```
           item
1/2/2024  apple
1/5/2024  apple
1/6/2024  apple
            item
1/3/2024  orange
1/5/2024  orange
1/7/2024  orange
            item
1/4/2024  banana
1/5/2024  banana
1/6/2024  banana
1/7/2024  banana
```

I want to combine the item values (comma separated) from each dataframe based on the date index.

I would like the resulting dataframe to look like this:

```
                         item
1/2/2024                apple
1/3/2024               orange
1/4/2024               banana
1/5/2024  apple,orange,banana
1/6/2024         apple,banana
1/7/2024        orange,banana
```

It seems like a simple problem but sorry I am a newbie doing python part-time and I just can't figure it out.  Thank you so much for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate all three dataframes, group by the index, then join the rows in each group:

```
df = pd.concat([s1, s2, s3]).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: ",".join(x))
```

```
                         item
1/2/2024                apple
1/3/2024               orange
1/4/2024               banana
1/5/2024  apple,orange,banana
1/6/2024         apple,banana
1/7/2024        orange,banana
```

Answer (score 2):

[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) grouping on the index:

```
out = pd.concat([s1, s2, s3]).groupby(level=0).agg(','.join)
```

Output:

```
                         item
1/2/2024                apple
1/3/2024               orange
1/4/2024               banana
1/5/2024  apple,orange,banana
1/6/2024         apple,banana
1/7/2024        orange,banana
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate DataFrames along the index:

```
result = pd.concat([s1, s2, s3], axis=0)
```

Group by index and aggregate the items into a comma-separated list:

```
result = result.groupby(result.index)['item'].agg(','.join)
```

Create a new DataFrame with the aggregated items:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'item': result})
```